# Typescript interface - field with type: MyInterface | string, not working when trying to access property

Tags: angular, typescript, mongoose, types, interface

I'm trying to recreate my mongoose object on my Angular app, so I'm trying to make interfaces.
The problem is that I'm not always sending my object with populated fields so I have something like this:

```
export interface Action {
  _id: string
  document: Document | string,
}
export interface Document {
  _id: string
  ...otherFields
}
```

And In my code I have something like:

```
const data = {
  documentId: action.document?._id
}
```

But I'm getting this error that block compilation:

```
Property '_id' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

So, how to make it work with both types?

Comment: what do you want it to do if it's a string?

Comment: @NicholasTower  Both interface are from mongoDB, and document is a reference in action object. So if I make the population, document is an object but if not it's a string

Comment: What i mean is, what do you want `data.documentId` to be set to if `action.document` is a string? Most likely candidates are the string itself, or undefined.

Answer (score 1):

When using [type unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types), you have to cast the complex types to use their properties:

```
const data = {
  documentId: (action.document as Document)?._id
}
```

If you want to store a `string` for document in your interface for `Action`, I would make an additional optional property to save you from having to cast `document`.:

```
export interface Action {
  document?: Document,
  docString?: string
}
```

Be aware that `document` is a reserved word in javascript. I'd use `doc` or something else.

Comment: If `action.document` can never be null or undefined, what's the purpose of the `?.`?

Comment: they can be null, just not undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best way to deal with it, but since you are using Union Type, you cand do a if check before set your document id like:

```
if(typeof(action.document !== 'string')) {
   const data = {     
     documentId: action.document?._id
   }  
}
```

Pretending that when it's a string it didn't get the right value.

Comment: This code is invalid JS/TS.  You can't write an `if` statement inside an object literal that way.

Comment: That's right, thanks for the heads up, I've edited it, I guess now it will work

Answer (score 0):

Since `action.document` could be multiple incompatible types, you'll need to add some code to check the type. Assuming you want to use the string if it's a `string`, then that can be done like this:

```
const data = {
  documentId: typeof action.document === 'string' ? action.document : action.document._id
}
```

In the second part of that ternary expression, typescript knows that the document can no longer be a `string`, and by process of elimination it knows it must be a `Document`. Therefore, it will let you access the `._id` property.